# Structure of auto increment index in MySQL,InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

When I use auto increment index,it is more efficient. ---《High Performance MySQL》

High Performance MySQL
[image]

But B+ tree's build process is flow：

B+ tree build
[image]

It is not full or 15/16 ,only half in the red circle,and never insert data in the future in the red circle when I use auto increment index.

So,it is contradictory.

And I guess,mysql although used B+ tree as index, but auto increment index not use the build way of B+ tree, mysql redesigned his own strategy for high performance.

Is my guess right?

Comment: Are you saying that the book is inconsistent?  Or that InnoDB does not do what the book says?

Comment: I mean if I used  auto increment index, the B+ tree build process should be picture 2,and half of the space is wasted . But the book saying use auto increment index has compact space.

Comment: chensir -- Jeremy Cole has some good tools for inspecting InnoDB structures.  How about getting them, and using them to answer your Question.  (Then post your Answer and Accept it.)  I don't have a definitive answer, but I am quite curious.

Comment: OK,thank you. I already find the answer.You can look at the area of Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok，I find the answer. because mysql have special optimization treatment.if the key is auto increment,build b+tree in the first way,otherwise,build b +tree in the second way.